# How can I merge/join then sort with mongodb

Tags: mysql, join, mongodb

I have an entries collection and a domain collection like the following

entries:

```
{
    {
        entry_id:1,
        title:"Title 1",
        domain_id:1
    },
    {
        entry_id:2,
        title:"Title 2",
        domain_id:1
    },
    {
        entry_id:3,
        title:"Title 3",
        domain_id:2
    }
}
```

domains:

```
{
    {
        domain_id:1,
        domain:"Google",
        rank:1
    },
    {
        domain_id:2,
        domain:"Yahoo",
        rank:2
    }
}
```

I am looking to gather all the information together and sort by the rank of the domain. Coming from a MySQL background I would normally join the entries and domains on the domain_id and sort by the rank field. One of my co-workers suggested looking into map/reduce, but after doing some reading I'm unsure how to apply that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your co-worker said, [Map/Reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce).

MongoDB is a document-based database. Probably a better pattern to follow in your scheme is to put entries inside the domains, see how much DRY it is:

```
{
    {
        domain_id:1,
        domain:"Google",
        rank:1,
        entries: [
          { 
            _id: dsfdsailfub3i4b23i4b234234,
            title: "the title"
          },
          { 
            _id: dsfdsailfub3i4b23i4b234234,
            title: "the title"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        domain_id:2,
        domain:"Yahoo",
        rank:2
    }
}
```

That's the easy part. you can now easily query a certain domain. Now, if you want to know how many entries each domain has you `map` each entry to return 1, and you `reduce` all those ones to find out their sum.

Here are several great answers to [what exactly is Map/Reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388321/what-is-map-reduce). Once you wrap your head around the idea it will be easy to implement it in Mongo.