# Why MapReduce is is named like that?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am a beginner in Hadoop. I am trying to understand why MapReduce is named like that.

From what I understand it's basically transforming for filtering the data first and then aggregating it to produce some output.

Why that filtering or transforming is called mapping? How is that operation can be considered as mapping?

Why that aggregate operation is called reducing? Here at least I can imagine that aggregate will reduce the input data set to a limited number of values.

I am trying to understand the meaning of MapReduce from a semantic perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the reasoning behind the terms of MapReduce, we must go back to the roots of those elements that make up this particular programming paradigm. This means we need to talk (as much precise and as less boring as possible) about **functional programming**.

In short, functional programming for [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) is:

> a declarative programming paradigm in which function definitions are trees of expressions that map values to other values, rather than a sequence of imperative statements which update the running state of the program.

This basically means that the emphasis of this model is on the application of functions and *not* on the imperative programming that is focused on the changes being made to a state. So by using functional code, a function in execution doesn't really rely on or manipulate data outside of its scope (as brilliantly said [here](https://maryrosecook.com/blog/post/a-practical-introduction-to-functional-programming)).

> *"Ok, and what does that have to do with MapReduce, anyhow?"*

Well, MapReduce is directly inspired by functional programming, because the Map and Reduce functions are the basic functions used in functional programming. Of course, MapReduce has many other added stages for an execution like *Combine*, *Shuffle*, *Sort*, etc., but the core idea of the model stems from that idea of functional programming described above.

About mapping, in a functional sense it is described as a function that receives two arguments, a function and a list of values. The Map function is essentially implementing the function upon each and every one value of the list to return an output list of results. You can indeed call this a type of "filtering", however data can be manipulated in a lot more ways than just "filtering" them out. The main goal of a Map function is changing input data to the desired form for the calculations being made up next in the Reduce function.

Talking about Reduce now, it follows a similar approach. Two arguments are given here as well, a function and a list of values where the function is going to be implemented. Since the list of values here is the transformed collection of data from the output of the Map function, all left to do is work on them and reach to the desired results. With your knowledge of the abstract sense of that step of a MapReduce job, you have the right idea when you describe the Reduce function as trying to aggregate the input data. The one thing that is "missing" from that procedure, though, is *how* and based on *what* will those input data be aggregated. And this is the main essence of the Map function, as described above.

With all this, we are able to understand that the MapReduce model is named after those two basic functions of functional programming that is abstractly implementing, so the model essentially follows the semantic contracts of the latter.

You can go on a quest yourself about all of this and a lot more by starting from [here](https://www.fincher.org/tips/General/SoftwareEngineering/FunctionalProgramming.shtml), [here](https://coderscat.com/understanding-mapreduce/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388329/5644037), and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220605/why-big-data-needs-to-be-functional).