# MapReduce mapping

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am learning the MapReduce framework and have the following questions about the same:

1. The MapReduce paradigm essentially has `map()` and `reduce()` (and a few others as well).  Can all the programming logic be effectively represented as either a `map()` or a `reduce()`?

   For e.g., suppose I want to do an in-order traversal of a tree.  Can this task be effectively divided only into a `map()` and `reduce()` task?  If yes, how?  If no, then how do I leverage the `MapReduce` framework for this task?

Generic code for [in-order traversal](https://java2blog.com/binary-tree-inorder-traversal-in-java/):

```
// Iterative solution
public void inOrderIter(TreeNode root) {

    if(root == null)
        return;

    Stack<TreeNode> s = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    TreeNode currentNode=root;

    while(!s.empty() || currentNode!=null){

        if(currentNode!=null)
        {
            s.push(currentNode);
            currentNode=currentNode.left;
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNode n=s.pop();
            System.out.printf("%d ",n.data);
            currentNode=n.right;
        }
    }
}
```

2. Can we have only a `map()` without a corresponding `reduce()` and vice versa?
3. As per [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/08/01/can-your-programming-language-do-this/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30655/8600195), the `reduce()` function generates the final output - is it necessary that it should generate only a *single* value?
4. How do you decide if a certain task should be a part of `map()` or `reduce()`?
5. Any general pointers about how to `map`-ify and `reduc`-ify a given task?

Comment: I tried explaining your queries. Kindly check.

Comment: @gyan, thank you.  It answers all my questions! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your queries:

> The MapReduce paradigm essentially has `map()` and `reduce()` (and a few
>   others as well). Can all the programming logic be effectively
>   represented as either a `map()` or a `reduce()`?

`MapReduce` is a design pattern and hence suitable only for those problem cases, which fits in BigData context. Although you may be able to solve a problem via an algorithm which involves a series of map-reduce, but it may not be the most efficient code from execution parameters (resource and time required). At the same time, a traditional algorithm may not work at all (merely because you have too large data); while `mapreduce` may help.

> Can we have only a `map()` without a corresponding `reduce()` and vice
>   versa?

In Java API, you may have `mapreduce` with no reduce phase, but not vice-versa. Although, you have option for default `IdentityMapper` to use.

> As per this and this, the reduce() function generates the final output
>   - is it necessary that it should generate only a single value?

No, you can write as many value out of a mapper/reducer through `context.write()` method, as long as you honor the output types as per API.

> How do you decide if a certain task should be a part of `map()` or
>   `reduce()`?

The majority of the problem solved in map reduce belongs to aggregation, joining two data-set, and some kind of funneling down data to deduce a result. If you understand the concept and processing steps in `mapreduce`, you should be able to decide what to write in `map()` and/or `reduce()`.

> Any general pointers about how to map-ify and reduc-ify a given task?

Again it depends on what you want to achieve. In general, `map()` is about reading data-set, filter them (if there may be unwanted records, or part of records) and decide on what all data needs to be clubbed together against a single key. Reducer is about processing the collection of data against a key (written by mapper).