# How can I make an one-user input have consequences in the behaviour of all page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

Is a very simple page, that have some buttons redirecting to external links. That external links have to change arbitrarely when certain people decides it.

I was wondering about making a login screen in other page and depending which user logs in, set the link writting it in a txt file that would be recovered by the main page. Don't need security so i just would make the user go to the other page and login and that would change the link in a txt file hosted in the same directory that the index.html is.

The problem is that i cannot make that idea (writing a .txt in the project folder) with JavaScript (or i think so), and i don't think that using a database worth it (neither want to because i read that would have to use node.js or something like that and i really don't know those tecnologies, only some python and sql server -that is in fact not supported by my hosting service-), cause are just 3 people associated to 1 link each. I can easily make that task with python but don't know how to call it from JS and neither if Ajax request would be useful for this case.

I hope someone can help me!

edit - the changes have to apply for the page itself not in the user session, so everyone who enters see the page with the changes

edit 2 - absolutely all the info (users and links) are always the same, doesnt change so i can put it in variables, are just 4 or 5 so i can easily use an array, the only thing that i would have to register is which one to pick (since it depends on who decides it).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT seems you want to use some sort of client side storage across different html pages - for that, you can use cookies, localSotrage or sessionStorage.

Comment: No no, i want that when this user make some certain action (like logging with a simple form or just pressing a button), the link in the buttons changed for anyone who enters in the page

Comment: Oh ok. You need to implement this on back-end then, so I would suggest database for that...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265666/best-server-side-data-storage-method-for-simple-data

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, anyway thank you for the reply!