# How to use Server Side storage for textbox values

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use Server Side Storage to store a value of a textbox in Server Side Storage when you click a save button. What would be the easiest way to use Server Side Storage? Do I need to use any other programming languages? I  also want to load the saved value of the textbox on window load.

Comment: this one is somehow related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265666/best-server-side-data-storage-method-for-simple-data

Comment: Filesystem or database are your two basic options. If database, then you need bit of SQL in the mix. SQLite would be plenty for you, easy enough to use with PHP PDO. Otherwise, serialize your data e.g. with `json_encode()` and store it somewhere. Outside the webroot if it contains any sensitive data. You'd have to match users to content though. Might be easier to just use [WebStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage) and save it in the user's browser, if all you need to do is to show again something.

Comment: @MarkusAO how could I use` json_encode()` where could I store the data?

Comment: On your filesystem. `file_put_contents($path, json_encode($data));` as simple as that.